# max cut estimation in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I understand what a max cut is. But I'm little confused because in this exercise they ask **whether the estimation is correct or not**. This is one of the examples:

[image: examples]

For me, there is only one MAXCUT in a graph, so how am I supposed to understand MAXCUT $\ge 4$ ?

Comment: The question is asking you if the maximum cut in that graph is at least $4$.

Comment: Ok, but what am I supposed to do if I think that it's true (just show a max cut of $4$ ?), and what should I do - how to prove - that it is not $\ge 4$(show max cut of $3$?)

Comment: If it is true, show a cut of size at least $4$. If it isn't true, you need an argument to explain why no cut can have size $4$ or more...

Comment: ok, let's consider the Petersen graph. They told me "estimate a max cut as best as you can from above and below". My answer is: $3 \le MAXCUT \le 11$, according to informations above I can say: $3$ because I can show a max cut of $3$, and $11$  because, I am able to show a max cut of $11$. If someone thinks it isn't true they need to give me an argument that explain why no cut can have size $3$ or $11$, but I can draw $3$ and $11$, ergo my estimation is correct, right ?